# How can I send request to server

Tags: android, server

I trying to send request after press button to server but server not received it. I connect to project gridmi api library in gradle file and synchronize it. How can I send request?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    GridmiAPI.init("http://localhost/demo/", 10000, JSONObject.class);

    GridmiAPI.Request request = new GridmiAPI.Request("message");

    GridmiAPI.onRequest(this, request, new GridmiAPI.Handler.OUT() {

        @Override
        protected void onSuccess(GridmiAPI.Response response) {
            Log.d("logsuc", "ok");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onFailed(Exception exception) {
        }

    });

}
```

I need update mysql table after received request via php

Comment: Is it failing? If so, what's the exception message?

Comment: `"http://localhost/....` So your server runs on the same device your app is running on?

Comment: there is no exception

Comment: yes. I trying to run android emulator

Comment: SO that request won't be added to the queue or executed? @kolive1401 it seems to me that instructions are incomplete.

Comment: It just does not send a request to the server. There is no answer and exception.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: see the answer posted. and try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the start method after `onRequest`:

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    GridmiAPI.init("http://localhost/demo/", 10000, JSONObject.class);

    GridmiAPI.Request request = new GridmiAPI.Request("message");

    GridmiAPI.onRequest(this, request, new GridmiAPI.Handler.OUT() {

        @Override
        protected void onSuccess(GridmiAPI.Response response) {
            Log.d("logsuc", "ok");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onFailed(Exception exception) {
        }

    }).start();

}
```

Also make sure `http://localhost/demo/` is the real server path and `10000` is the correct port.

Comment: Fine! Working! Thank u